# How to convert JavaScript functions to jQuery for a countdown timer on load of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdowntimer

I have the following code for a countdown timer. I need to convert the JavaScript portion to jQuery. The countdown timer starts on page load. How can I do that, as I have to load the diffTime function on load of the page. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I got that the jquery call can not access ** function Tick() ** from ** function CreateTimer() ** . Is there any library for ** setTimeout() ** in jQuery? As I know so far, it is native to JS.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Timer;
        var TotalSeconds;


        function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) {
            Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
            TotalSeconds = Time;
            //UpdateTimer()
            window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
        }

        function Tick() {
            if (TotalSeconds <= 0) {
                //alert("Time's up!")
                document.getElementById("timeMsg").innerHTML = "Market closed!! ";
                return;
            }

            TotalSeconds -= 1;
            UpdateTimer()
            window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
        }

        function UpdateTimer() {
            var Seconds = TotalSeconds;

            var Days = Math.floor(Seconds / 86400);
            Seconds -= Days * 86400;

            var Hours = Math.floor(Seconds / 3600);
            Seconds -= Hours * (3600);

            var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);
            Seconds -= Minutes * (60);


            var TimeStr = ((Days > 0) ? Days + " days " : "") + LeadingZero(Hours) + ":" + LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds)


            Timer.innerHTML = TimeStr;
        }



        function LeadingZero(Time) {

            return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : + Time;

        }

        function diffTime(){

            var startTime = 10*60 + 30; //starting time in minute
            var lastTime = 16*60 + 30;  //ending time in minutes

            var thisTime = new Date();              // now
            var currentYear = thisTime.getFullYear();        
            var currentMonth = thisTime.getMonth();
            var currentDay = thisTime.getUTCDate();
            var currentHour = thisTime.getHours();
            var currentMinute = thisTime.getMinutes();

            var currentTime = currentHour*60 + currentMinute;   //current time in minute

            if(currentTime >= startTime && currentTime < lastTime){

                var endTime = new Date(currentYear,currentMonth,currentDay,16,30);  // 4:30pm           

                var diff = endTime.getTime() - thisTime.getTime();   // now
                var remainTime = diff / (1000);     // positive number of days
                remainTime = Math.ceil(remainTime);
                CreateTimer("timer", remainTime);


            }else{
                document.getElementById("timeMsg").innerHTML = "Market closed!! ";
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "00:00:00";

            }

        }
        window.onload = diffTime;
    </script>


</head>
<body>

    <div><span id="timeMsg">Elapsed time remain: </span><b><span id='timer'></span></b></div>


</body>
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't tried converting it at all.

Comment: Do your research on the basics first. Try to learn what exactly is JavaScript and what is JQuery and you will have your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function in  document.ready()

```
 $( document ).ready( function ()
    {

diffTime();
});
```

Comment: Did you include the jquery library in your page?

Comment: thank you.
I have used
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

But I think it can't access function Tick(). I don't know why, Is there any library for setTimeout() in jQuery, As far as i know it is native to JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to start after the entire (ie. images, objects, etc.) page has loaded:

```
$(window).load(function() {}
```

Otherwise you can start the timer when the HTML has been loaded & DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {}
```

Comment: Thank you tenub. I have tried the both way, but it didn't work.